# How to have onClick Javascript event on Flash object

Tags: javascript, flash, google-analytics, dom-events

I want to have an onClick event on flashObjects to fire the google analytics event tracking for every click on Flash. What is the best way to accomplish this?

I don't have access to Flash source code that's why I want to do it with Javascript event.

edit: I found a workaround for this, don't know if its the right way though

```
<div onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','CommerceAd', 'IMAGE2000 Click', 'HomePage - Primary', 'sandybridge-horizon-banner']);">
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/BannerImages/1103/sandybridge-horizon-banner.swf" width="98%" height="120">
    <param name="movie" value="/BannerImages/1103/sandybridge-horizon-banner.swf"/>
    <param name="flashvars" value="clickTAG=/some-url.html"/> 
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
  </object>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use Javascript if you want Google Analytics within Flash. There is library for that:

http://code.google.com/intl/sk/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/flashTrackingIntro.html

I've done it many times using it and it works perfectly.

```
playGame.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClick ); 
function onButtonClick( event:Event ):void 
{     
  tracker.trackPageview( "/started-game");
  //if user started game you'll see it as an access of subpage "/started-game" in your Analytics account

}
```

Comment: I don't have access to flash source code thats why I want to do it with javascript event

Comment: Probably the only solution is to overlay the Flash with some transparent HTML object (such as z-indexed DIV) and put Javascript on it. Your Flash will unfortunately stop to receive clicks (MouseEvents). :/